# Sending mail with php shows via

Tags: php, email, gmail

I am sending mail with php mail() function. It shows via secureserver.net. Please see screenshot and how to remove it?[image]

Comment: Mail server config, mail daemon config (smtp), reverse DNS, etc. can all cause that.

Answer (score 0):

Sending mail with [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) is actually more difficult than it seems. You need to worry about [SPF Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework), deliverability based on your servers reputation, not being a trusted domain in Barracuda could get your messages filtered. If your domain black listed, sending mail could become a real problem.

I'm not even going to get into how difficult it is to send HTML and attachments properly.

The two options I suggest are to use either a package dedicated to dealing with mail, such as [SwiftMailer](https://packagist.org/packages/swiftmailer/swiftmailer), or even using a mail service to send the mail for you, like [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) there are free options available.

These are not the only packages or services you can use, just a couple examples.